# where is the function derivable?

Tags: functions

I've got this function graph and need to know where it is derivable, am i only able to say that it is derivable only where the function has smooth variation i.e to say it's derivable on $I-{\pi/6, 5\pi/6, \pi}$

The function is $$|1/2 -\sin x|+1/2-|\sin x|$$
and its graph is the following [image]

considering the domain :I=[0,2$\pi$] only

Comment: Hint: your function is the sum of three summands. Look at the arguments where the single summands have no derivative, i.e. the arguments for which at least one of  the $|\dots|$ are zero.

Comment: Why $\pi/6$ and $5\pi/6$ ?

Comment: This is not the right function.

Comment: yep sorry ill edit it now, its sin(x) instead of 2sin(x)

Answer (score 0):

A function f is differentiable at a point c if $\lim{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$

If this limit exists it is equal to $f'(c)$.

Limit exists means limit should exist and be equal to each other while both approaching from LHS and RHS. Thats why the edge points of your function are not differentiable points.